# Angular = reset conditional form control with the same name

Tags: angular

I have the following code (kind of):

```
<input *ngIf="a" #autocomplete formControl="myControl">
<input *ngIf="!a" #autocomplete formControl="myControl">
```

Those inputs have different attributes, based on condition 1st or 2nd input should step in.
At some point, I reset the control:

```
this.myControl.setValue('')
this.myControl.reset()
```

From UI perspective, only first condition works properly - the field gets erased, and when I debug and check `autocomplete.nativeElementValue` it shows empty string (an on the screen I see empty input). But when I run into the second condition, input remains with the same string on the screen, and `autocomplete.nativeElementValue` has this value as well.

Could you advise why this is happening? Is it something wrong because I use the same input names, even if they exist uniquely in the component template?

Comment: you can handle all this conditions on your ts file and your form.

Answer (score 0):

As [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) suggest:

> With structural directives, such as *ngFor or *ngIf, there is no way for Angular to know if a template is ever instantiated.

If you are using `FormControl` you can directly change value on it by accessing it from the `FormGroup`. It's not clear what `this.myControl` refers to, but if you are using `@ViewChild` it will just look at the first instance of your `#autocomplete` and go no further. I also don't understand why you have two instances of the same `input`. Is it because of validation? If so you can conditionally change `Validators` on the input and not the input itself.